# How to blacklist built-in Kernel module 8250_pci

Tags: kernel

I'm trying to blacklist built-in Linux Kernel module 8250_pci using modprobe.blacklist=8250_pci as boot option without success, how can avoid loading this one?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Unix & Linux StackExchange!

If the `8250_pci` driver is built into the kernel, `modprobe.blacklist` will have no effect at all to it, since `modprobe` will not be involved at all.

Instead, you could pipe the PCI bus ID of the device in question to `/sys/bus/pci/drivers/serial_pci/unbind` to unplug the driver from a particular device. (The pathname might be `.../serial/unbind` instead, I cannot check at the moment.)

Example:

```
echo 0000:03:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/serial_pci/unbind
```

If there is a `remove_id` in the same directory, you might also pipe the vendor & product IDs (use `lspci -nn` to see them) of the device in question into it, so the driver will not be picking the device up again if the serial device auto-detection is triggered for any reason.

Example:

```
echo "1415 c158" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/serial_pci/remove_id
```

Once you find the right value(s) to pipe into the pseudo-file(s), you might want to add them into `/etc/rc.local` or write your own small start-up script (or a `.service` file if applicable) to run the commands at every boot.

Comment: My PCIe device is 03:00.0  Can you post a command line example for the unbinding, assuming /sys/bus/pci/drivers/serial_pci/unbind for the unbind? I then need to load another driver for this device.

Comment: OK Thank you very much, echo “0000:03:00.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/serial/unbind did the trick and now only the vendor's driver shows loaded in lspci -v. This was to override "serial" kernel driver and 8250_pci.ko and employ the vendor's loadable module instead on a WCH382L based PCIe serial card (2 serial ports). However, the serial ports still doesn't work, maybe I now have to bind to the vendor's drivers? They appear loaded in lspci -v though. If I have to bind to new drivers, I don't see them anywhere on /sys/bus/ path.

Comment: With a bit of googling, I found a Linux driver for WCH382L, version 2.0.0.1. The README provided with it says it should support kernel versions starting from 2.4 up to at least 3.6, and there are no actual files newer than year 2012. It doesn't seem to use the current Linux device probing concepts: instead, the module initialization function will also probe for hardware once at module load time, and that's it. (Maybe `rmmod` and then reload the vendor driver once you've unbound the standard one.) There should be plenty of messages from the vendor driver in the `dmesg` output.

Comment: No worries about the driver, the chip manufacturer sent me a new enough one which I was able to modify to compile on my 5.0.16 Linux Kernel. wch.ko module was created and it loads correctly. However, despite unbinding device and modprobing again the wch driver, the ports are still non-functional. In lspci -v appears the module loaded for device is wch (now that serial was unbinded) but no kernel driver appears "in use" state.